# How to make an API call using meteor

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter, meteor

Ok here is the twitter API,

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=perkytweets
```

Can any one give me any hint about how to go about calling this API or link using [Meteor](http://meteor.com)

***Update::***

Here is the code that i tried but its not showing any response

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        return "Welcome to HelloWorld";
    };

    Template.hello.events({
        'click input' : function () {
            checkTwitter();
        }
    });

    Meteor.methods({checkTwitter: function () {
        this.unblock();
        var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=perkytweets");
        alert(result.statusCode);
    }});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    });
}
```

Comment: I had a quick look at the docs and i reckon it will be useful to look at http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http_get , although i havent used meteor before so im not too sure the syntax, but ill have a look now for you...

Comment: The documentation for `HTTP.get()` is now at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are defining your checkTwitter [Meteor.method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) **inside** a client-scoped block. Because you cannot call cross domain from the client (unless using jsonp), you have to put this block in a `Meteor.isServer` block.

[As an aside, per the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods), the client side `Meteor.method` of your checkTwitter function is merely a **stub** of a server-side method. You'll want to check out the docs for a full explanation of how server-side and client-side `Meteor.methods` work together.

Here is a working example of the http call:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        checkTwitter: function () {
            this.unblock();
            return Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=perkytweets");
        }
    });
}

//invoke the server method
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call("checkTwitter", function(error, results) {
        console.log(results.content); //results.data should be a JSON object
    });
}
```

Comment: well it actually returns xml and not json,so while trying to do an alert it shows undefined

Comment: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=perkytweets (edited above) -- and more importantly, did this work?

Comment: well actually i tried with ur updated answer too,i'm getting a response but it is [object][object].Is it possible to convert it into string.I'm mean in normal javascript we can use jquery JSON.stringify to convert json to string but here if i try dat i'm getting {"error":{}}

Comment: I just ran the code and it looks good. `results.content` should give you a string. I'm editing my answer though, as option 1 isn't going to fly -- you cannot do cross domain ajax client side (unless leveraging jsonp, but I don't want to complicate things).

Comment: Also note for anyone reading this in retrospect: You need to make the response of this async call available as a reactive variable, for example by storing it into a Session variable, which you then print in the template (and autoupdate when the async call completes).

Comment: Silently fails without the package, so `meteor add http`.

Comment: Hi, where are you using the API keys? Is it running without API keys?

Answer (score 29):

This might seem rudimentary - but the HTTP package does not come by default in your Meteor project and requires that you install it a la carte.

On the command line either:

1. Just Meteor: 
   meteor add http
2. Meteorite: 
   mrt add http

[Meteor HTTP Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#http)

Answer (score 6):

Meteor.http.get on the client is async, so you will need to provide a callback function :

```
Meteor.http.call("GET",url,function(error,result){
     console.log(result.statusCode);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Meteor.http.get`. Per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http_get):

> ```
> Meteor.http.get(url, [options], [asyncCallback]) Anywhere
> Send an HTTP GET request. Equivalent to Meteor.http.call("GET", ...).
> ```

The docs actually include some examples of using Twitter, so you should be able to get started with them.

Comment: thnks for dat..i just updated my code but its still not working.Showing no output

Answer (score 0):

on server side if you provide the call back to http.get it will be asynch call so my solutions to that undefined return on client was

var result = HTTP.get(iurl);
return result.data.response;

as i did not pass a call back to HTTP.get so it waited until i got response. hope it helps