# How To Integrate Meteor.js As A Front End Only Framework With My Django App

Tags: django, meteor

I need to use the meteor.js as a front end framework in my django app. I know meteor is a full stack framework; How can I use it as a front end framework only with my Django app.
I know, Angular.js, backbone.js kind of frameworks should be used for that. But I have to use meteor.js only for completing my exercise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your Django App As a API Rest. and in the Meteor App in the client side you can call the API with the HTTP.get method

HTTP.get(url, [callOptions], [asyncCallback])

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get

Meteor (Blaze) Have the space bars for iterate and take desicions:

https://www.meteor.com/blaze

This Topic is similar to your question:

[How to make an API call using meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320610/how-to-make-an-api-call-using-meteor)