# Can I add meteor to one part of my app which is written in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, meteor, laravel-5, single-sign-on

I have my app written in Laravel 5.3, however I want that my app core functionality be written in meteorjs. I was thinking that I should introduce SSO, so user can be authenticated straight away when it goes from laravel to meteor framework, so I'm wondering is this a good way? Also is it possible to have myapp.com written in laravel and myapp.com/core in meteorjs?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Why do you want to write your application using two very different frameworks? What benefit does each provide that the other lacks? How exactly would you want them to interact?

Comment: Well I have rewritten my native PHP code to L5.3 and mostly its ok, but I dont want to add up angular to make SPA App, thats why I want one part of my app to be fully SPA and that is my core app.

Comment: Meteor is designed to be a front-end _and back-end_ framework. But it sound like you only want the front-end part. Maybe [this question about using Meteor with a Django back-end will help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31028553/354577). Django and Laravel are very different frameworks, but the general approach should still apply.