# Make api call in Meteor

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

How can I achieve the same result as the following curl code in Meteor?

```
curl https://pwint.ly/api/v1.0/Page \
   -u test_48c1a7647c6a419ebc9109f6150a7925:9b758ef621d44be2b51a3e913a58ca97 \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d {'urls':[{'original':'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8593/15663081584_0e51fa0841_o_d.jpg',}],'yourid':'1234','returnurl':'http://www.example.com/returnurl'}
```

I have attempted to use the Meteor http package like this:

```
  apiCall : function () {
        var result = HTTP.post("https://pwint.ly/api/v1.0/Page", {

         data: {'urls':[{'original':'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8593/15663081584_0e51fa0841_o_d.jpg'}],'yourid':'1234','returnurl':'http://192.168.1.141:3000'}

        });

        console.log(result.content)
        console.log(result.data) //<< JSON form (if api reports application/json as the content-type h
  }
```

But I receive this error:

```
Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
W20150823-12:13:19.648(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.HTTP.post (packages/http/httpcall_common.js:56:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.648(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.call (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.648(-4)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.apiCall (app\art.js:48:24)
W20150823-12:13:19.648(-4)? (STDERR)     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.649(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1530:1
W20150823-12:13:19.649(-4)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.apply (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1529:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.649(-4)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.650(-4)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.call (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1472:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.650(-4)? (STDERR)     at app\art.js:68:8
W20150823-12:13:19.650(-4)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Raj\art\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
W20150823-12:13:19.650(-4)? (STDERR)     at app\art.js:244:3
W20150823-12:13:19.651(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150823-12:13:19.651(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20150823-12:13:19.651(-4)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\Raj\art\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:117:5
W20150823-12:13:19.651(-4)? (STDERR)     - - - - -
W20150823-12:13:19.651(-4)? (STDERR)     at makeErrorByStatus (packages/http/httpcall_common.js:12:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.652(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request._callback (packages/http/httpcall_server.js:109:1)
W20150823-12:13:19.652(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\http\1.1.0\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:344:22)
W20150823-12:13:19.652(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
W20150823-12:13:19.652(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\http\1.1.0\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1239:14)
W20150823-12:13:19.652(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
W20150823-12:13:19.653(-4)? (STDERR)     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Raj\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\http\1.1.0\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1187:12)
W20150823-12:13:19.653(-4)? (STDERR)     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
W20150823-12:13:19.653(-4)? (STDERR)     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
W20150823-12:13:19.654(-4)? (STDERR)     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: this is an api call from the meteor client to the server?  something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320610/how-to-make-an-api-call-using-meteor

Comment: Yes, but "apiCall" is a Meteor method defined on the server side.

Comment: ok, so you are trying to post from the meteor server to an external api correct?

Comment: When I get obscure errors like this my approach is usually to set a breakpoint on the line in the package that is breaking and then look at the state of the variables when I get there to see what's arrived broken and then backtrack to how I called the function. Given the short amount of code you are testing you can also interatively execute it from your browser console and debug it directly from there (especially since it appears your function is being run on the server).

Comment: When I attempted this just now I got back a 405 from the server. Try using the callback form of *HTTP.post* and looking at *err*.

Comment: Looks like the server you're trying to reach is sending you a status code different from 200. Can you put that `HTTP.post` within `try/catch` block and `console.log` whatever error you will receive?