# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on requested resource: Meteor server-side

Tags: http, meteor, xmlhttprequest, cors

I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097411/angular-meteor-enabling-cors-for-client-side-http-services
and since then have learned that I should be able to solve the titular error by making calls from the server-side instead. I have done this, even using access-control-origin headers, and I'm still receiving 
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load" and
"Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access"
I'm  also using the example query provided to me directly from the API providers themselves after I contacted them.

here's what I have on the server:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
Meteor.methods({
'inFetch': function(){
  var method = 'GET';
  var url = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?     
key=[thiskey]&q=carrot";
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Request-Method': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-         
Type, Accept, Authorization'
    }
  }
this.unblock();
Meteor.http.call(method, url, options, function(error, result){
if (error) {
     console.log('SERVER ERRR');
     return "error";
   } else{
     console.log('SERVER RESULT');
     return result;
 }
});

}
});
```

And here's what I have on the client:

```
function inFetch(){
  // food2fork get //
  $scope.inHits=[];
  $scope.preInHits=[];
  $scope.inHits= Meteor.call("inFetch");
```

}

I have been working on this problem for a long, long time and learned a lot about   HTTP request access, so I'm stumped that the above isn't fixing this, ala:

[How to make an API call using meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320610/how-to-make-an-api-call-using-meteor)

EDIT: removed link to original question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. Although I still need to parse it and get the JSON to my client page, but I've logged to console a successful API response using the above structure. The problem was a bug elsewhere in my code.  If anybody was wondering how to deal with annoying CORS denial with Meteor, hopefully you find this post.