# Meteor: Proper Way to Send a POST Request to Modulus API

Tags: node.js, api, meteor, modulus.io

I have a meteor application hosted on modulus.

Modulus has an api here: https://api.modulus.io/

The API code is hosted here: https://github.com/onmodulus/modulus-cli/blob/master/lib/librarian/librarian.js#L361

I want to save a domain to one of my deployments on modulus through the API.

I know this is the code I am looking to connect to: https://github.com/onmodulus/modulus-cli/blob/master/lib/librarian/librarian.js#L361

`librarian.project.saveDomains = function(projectId, domains, authToken, callback) {
  if(checkInit(callback)) {
    librarian._http.request(util.format('/project/%s/domains?authToken=%s', projectId, authToken), 'POST', domains, callback);
  }
};`

And I am new to making API calls.

I believe I need to make the call from the server in my meteor app, which could be handled using a meteor method, but I don't know what the API call should look like.

I've researched online and on SO. No luck and I am battling a lack of experience with API calls so I am looking from a little direction.

I've added the http package for meteor:

`meteor add http`

I think the following is in the ball park, but not currently working:

POST
`javascript
//save arguments object to options variable
var options = {
  projectId: xxx,
  domains: ["example.com"],
  authToken: settings.Modulus.authToken
}
//call meteor method from client
Meteor.call('saveDomainToModulus', options, function(error, result) {
  if (error)
    console.log(error)
  else
    console.log(result)
  }
});
//on server
Meteor.methods({
  "saveDomainToModulus": function(options) {
    var apiEndpoint = "http://api.modulus.io/project/%s/domains?authToken=" + options.authToken;
    HTTP.post( apiEndpoint,
      options.projectId,
      options.domains,
      options.authToken,
      function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        console.log( response );
      }
    });
  }
})`

Feels like I'm starting to close in on a solution, but if anyone with more experience has any feedback, let me know.

Comment: Appears that the key to making this work lies in wrapAsync: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server. Still working on it. Any light shed is welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an API call using meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320610/how-to-make-an-api-call-using-meteor)